# Passing url to spider in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to passing the url to my spider but after looking through what others have done in stack overflow I am always getting the following error:

```
raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)
```

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong? Just trying to learn how to se this api.

```
import scrapy
from drinkRecipe.items import DrinkrecipeItem
class RecipeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "recipe"
    allowed_domains = ["www.1001cocktails.com"]


    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('searchUrl')]
        super(RecipeSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('searchUrl')]
        print self.start_urls


    def parse(self, response):
        for selector in response.xpath('//a[contains(@title,"Cocktail")]'):
            href = selector.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            if href is not None:
                href = response.urljoin(href)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=href, callback=self.parse_Recipe)

    def parse_Recipe (self,response):
        item = DrinkrecipeItem()
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()[0][:-17]

        measurements = response.xpath('//td[@class="normal2"]/text()').re(r'.*oz.*')
        ingredients = []
        recipe = ""
        for selector  in response.xpath('//a[contains(@alt,"Recipes with")]'):
            ingredient = selector.xpath('u/text()').extract()[0]
            try:
                ingredients.append(str(ingredient))
            except:
                continue
        for i in range(len(measurements)):
            measurement = str(measurements[i]).replace("                  ","")
            recipe += measurement+ingredients[i]+":"
    item['recipe'] = recipe
        yield item
```

Main script that runs spider

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess, Crawler
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from drinkRecipe import DrinkrecipeItem,RecipeSpider

items = []


def scrapedItems(item, response, spider):
    items.append(item)

def main():
    settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler = Crawler(RecipeSpider(searchUrl='http://www.1001cocktails.com/recipes/cocktails/cocktails_list_vu.php3?&start=0'))
    crawler.signals.connect(scrapedItems,signal=signals.item_scraped)
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(crawler)
    process.start()
    print '-'*50
    print items
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured that I am an idiot for not realizing that I should have passed the arugument in process crawler in my script.